# how to bind Radio buttons in Silverlight datagrid row and read the selected value for each row in Viewmodel

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid and each row is having a set of radio buttons in 1 column. I have binded these radio buttons using a listbox datatemplate to generate Radiobuttons on the fly.

Here is the code for template:

```
<data:DataGrid   x:Name="formTemplate" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" HeadersVisibility="All"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FormFieldInformation,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
  <data:DataGrid.Columns>
       <data:DataGridTemplateColumn DisplayIndex="1">
              <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <RadioButton GroupName="GN1" Content="From" Width="50" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                       </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <data:DataGrid.Columns>
 </data:DataGrid>
```

But there are two problems here:
1. I can only select one single radio button among all the radio buttons generated for the whole datagrid. I want to select one radio button per row.
2. How do i get the selected radiobuttons value in ViewModel?

Any suggestions are appreciated in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

1) You need to give an unique `GroupName` to each `RadioButton` set. The easiest way I think is to bind the `GroupName` to a property on the class your are binding the datagrid to. Example, supose you have the class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Radio1IsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool Radio2IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

where "Id" is unique, bind it to the `GroupName` so each row will have a different one.

2) To get the checked value you will have to bind the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` to a property on your class. With the above class, it would be something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Id}" Content="From" IsChecked="{Binding Radio1IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Id}" Content="To" IsChecked="{Binding Radio2IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT1**

I supose the XAML code you posted is not the actual code you are running, right? Try this on your `CellTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Radios}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Now your class will have to be something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Radio> Radios { get; set; }
}


public class Radio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }   
}
```

Now you can have multiple RadioButtons (just add them to the Item.Radios list).

Does that work for you?

Comment: can you explain the second half: Reading value of selected radio button in the view model.

Comment: Your `FormFieldInformation` is a list of items, right? On that item class you need to have a boolean property to bind to the RadioButton. For each RadioButton, you will need a property. On my example I have the `Radio1IsChecked` and `Radio2IsChecked` binded to my view. When the user check a radio, the property on the class will change. Can you show your class that you are binding to the dataGrid?

Comment: Actually Radio buttons generated for each row are dynamic and each row may have different set of RadioButtons. What i can do in this scenario.

Comment: let me know if you have any problems.